# Proof on showing the integral of f(x)=0

Tags: integration, functions, proof-writing

I am having difficulties showing that if $f$ is continuous such that $f(x)<0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$ then $\int_a^bf(x)\;dx <0$

I am given the theorem that if $f$ is continuous such that $f(x)>0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$ then $\int_a^bf(x)\;dx>0$.

I have looked into theorem on calculus but none seem to be of any help that I have found so far.

Any help on how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you use the fact that $\int (-f) =-\int f$ ? My notation has obvious abbreviations. Or, said differently, $\int f = -\int (-f)$.

Comment: What would the negation of the function exactly do?

Comment: You can apply your original theorem to $(-f)$. Now you need to work out the details. Write it down and start manipulating it.

Comment: I think I have it. Just want to check can I assume if I create g=-f then g is continuous such that g(x) >0 for every x in (a,b)?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$, so is $g = -f$. Apply the given theorem to $g$, and we get what we want.

Comment: So to make sure I understand since f is continuous we can create a g such that g=-f and since we are assuming f(x)<0 for all x in (a,b) we can assume g(x)>0 for all x in (a,b) and then apply the theorem?